# Why std::is_assignable doesn't work with primitive types? (Confirmation)

Tags: c++, assign, assignment-operator, overloading

To be more specific why 
`std::is_assignable_v<int, int> << '\n';`
returns `false`? Is it because an int has no overloaded assignment operator (being a primitive type and all)?

(by the way `std::is_trivially_assignable_v<int, int>` gives `false` too.)

Note that this: 
`struct Structure {};
std::is_assignable<class Structure, class Structure>::value;`
would return `true`, because an overloaded assignment operator is implicitly defined for `Structure`.

Am i correct so far? If so then I suppose it wouldn't be trivial to enhance `is_assignable` to accept primitive types as well? Otherwise, any hints for such a possible work-around?

Comment: You could check if the type `is_fundemental` or `is_assignable`

Comment: Your example is discussed right on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If the expression `std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>()` is well-formed in unevaluated context

```
std::is_assignable<int, int>::value << '\n' // 1 = 1; wouldn't compile
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable

Answer (score 10):

An `int` cannot be assigned to an `int`. If you pass `int&` as a first argument instead, then, as expected, both `is_assignable` and `is_trivially_assignable` return `true`.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable), [godbolted](https://godbolt.org/z/qaDgbK)

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    static_assert(!std::is_assignable_v<int, int>);
    static_assert(std::is_assignable_v<int&, int>);
    static_assert(!std::is_trivially_assignable_v<int, int>);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_assignable_v<int&, int>);

    return 0;
}
```

A not so intuitive part — `is_assignable_v<mytype, mytype>` is true is because `mytype{} = mytype{};` works too, and only `is_assignable_v<mytype const, mytype>` is false.

Comment: I could not understand why int is not assignable by int, can you explain more?

Comment: @Jeka, I guess because you cannot say `int{42} = int{24}` (error: temporary as an lvalue), but you can say `mytype{42} = mytype{24}` (good question, why?). All `is_assignable` does is checking if assignment expression is well-formed.

Comment: @Jeka He meant in the context of `std::declval` (used by std::is_assignable internally) which returns an rvalue reference of its argument (compile time unevaluated context only). And as bobah explained you can't assign to an rvalue. Once I saw his wording there I knew it would be confusing to people.

Comment: @Nik-Lz - thanks for spelling it out, my comment was not less confusing than the std wording, I realized.